# Reading data from file using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am writing a ajax program in which I am reading data from files created in the project folder. I am having trouble when I select Pakistan country then select any province. Firstly cities in selected province come but when I change the Province all the cities in all province files come. I am trying for hours but not able to figure out. Please anyone can help

Here is my jQuery/ajax code:

```
switch (myProvince) {
    case 'Pakistan':
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "file/country/Pakistan.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
                var arrayProvince = response.split(',');
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayProvince.length; i++) {
                    $('#province').append('<option>' + arrayProvince[i] + '</option>');
                }
            }
        });


$('#province').change(function () {
    var myCity = $('#province option:selected').text();
    $("#city").find("option:not(:first)").remove();

    switch (myCity) {
        case 'KPK':
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "file/Province/KPK.txt",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (object) {
                    var arrayCity = object.split(',');
                    for (var j = 0; j < arrayCity.length; j++) {
                        $('#City').append('<option>' + arrayCity[j] + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
        case 'Punjab':
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "file/Province/Punjab.txt",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (object) {
                    var arrayCity = object.split(',');
                    for (var i = 0; i < arrayCity.length; i++) {
                        $('#City').append('<option>' + arrayCity[i] + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
        case 'Balochistan':
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "file/Province/Balochistan.txt",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (object) {
                    var arrayCity = object.split(',');
                    for (var i = 0; i < arrayCity.length; i++) {
                        $('#City').append('<option>' + arrayCity[i] + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
        case 'Kashmir':
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "file/Province/Kashmir.txt",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (object) {
                    var arrayCity = object.split(',');
                    for (var i = 0; i < arrayCity.length; i++) {
                            $('#City').append('<option>' + arrayCity[i] + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
        case 'Sindh':
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "file/Province/Sindh.txt",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (object) {
                    var arrayCity = object.split(',');
                    for (var i = 0; i < arrayCity.length; i++) {
                        $('#City').append('<option>' + arrayCity[i] + '</option>');
                }
            }
        });
        default:

    }
});
```

Here is my Html code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
        <select class="country form-control" id="country">
            Country
            <option disabled selected>Country</option>
            <option>Pakistan</option>
            <option>America</option>
            <option>Russia</option>
            <option>China</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
        <select class="country form-control" id="province">
            <option id="proDefault" disabled selected>State/Province</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
        <select class="country form-control" id="City">
            <option id="city" disabled selected>City</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI Instead of copying and pasting the code like that you could just use ```url: "file/Province/" + myCity + ".txt",```

Comment: Thanks this way i can get rid of switch statement. I will update that

Comment: Please, read [the documentation for the `switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: I know the use of switch statement  @MikeMcCaughan . but just forgot to add break at the end of each case. but this does not solve the problem for me. still the cities previously added are showing in the select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed your `switch` from province selection. You can do the same for countries, so your code will be significantly shorter with no duplication and much easier to maintain.

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/t9KnOtMucXkpWIpAfODB?p=preview)

```
$(function() {

  $('#country').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "Pakistan.txt",
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(response) {
        var arrayProvince = response.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayProvince.length; i++) {
          $('#province').append('<option>' + arrayProvince[i] + '</option>');
        }
      }
    });
  });

  $('#province').change(function() {
    var myCity = $('#province option:selected').text();

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: myCity + ".txt",
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(object) {
        $("#city").find("option:not(:first)").remove();

        var arrayCity = object.split(',');
        for (var j = 0; j < arrayCity.length; j++) {
          $('#city').append('<option>' + arrayCity[j] + '</option>');
        }
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: just a moment ago I changed my code exactly like this. and it worked. When I had a look at your code I got amazed that was exactly the same as i wrote.  Thank you so much for help though.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `break;` at the end of each `case` block.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Though it should have been there earlier. thanks for mentioning but even after adding break; at the end of each case block it is not working. The options added with first change are not getting removed on second change. new options are appending below earlier added rows

Comment: i mean this code  $("#city").find("option:not(:first)").remove();
is still not doing the job